# Can you load textures in a specific order?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm currently loading a different texture to each sphere face of a sphere geometry and at the moment it loads the textures from top down. Is there anyway to begin the loading of textures at say, the middle of the sphere and continue outwards?

Just for reference, this is how I'm currently assigning textures to each sphere face

```
var sphere  = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 250, geo_width, geo_height );   

var materials = []; 
for( var y = 0; y < geo_height; y++ ){
    for( var x = 0; x < geo_width; x++ ){
        materials.push( loadTexture('getImage.php?x=' + x + '&y=' + y + '&zoom=2&type=' + type ) );
    }   
}   

for( var i = 0; i < sphere.faces.length; i++ ){
    sphere.faces[ i ].materialIndex = i;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this. 
First of all, you should start loading textures in the order you want to display them. In your case you need to change your loops, to first load textures which are in the middle of the sphere.

```
var materials = new Array(geo_height*geo_width);
// loading middle part of textures
for( var y = yFrom; y < yTo; y++ ){
    for( var x = xFrom; x < xTo; x++ ){
        materials[y * geo_width + x] = loadTexture('getImage.php?x=' + x + '&y=' + y + '&zoom=2&type=' + type );
    }
}
// loading other textures
for( var y = 0; y < geo_height; y++ ){
    for( var x = 0; x < geo_width; x++ ){
        if (materials[y * geo_width + x] == undefined)
            materials[y * geo_width + x] = loadTexture('getImage.php?x=' + x + '&y=' + y + '&zoom=2&type=' + type );
    }
}
```

Sometimes if you want to be sure that some textures are loaded before others you can synchronize them by using load callback function. Use Imageutils.loadTexture(url, mapping, onLoad, onError) for this purpose. For example, loading textures by packs:

```
function loadTexturesPack(texturesPack, cb) {
    var count = 0,
        textures = [],
        onLoad = function() {
            count++;
            if (count == texturesPack.length) 
                cb(textures);
        };
    for (var i = 0; i < texturesPack.length; i++) {
        textures.push(Imageutils.loadTexture(texturesPack.url, null, onLoad));        
    }
}

function loadPacks(packs) {
    var i = 0;
        onLoad = function(textures) {
            i++;   
            // do something with loaded textures  
            // ...      
            // load next texture pack 
            if (i < packs.length) {
                loadTexturesPack(pack[i]);
            }
        };
    loadTexturesPack(pack[0]);
}
```